# Serialize avro into Kafka using schema registry and spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, registry, schema, spark-avro

I want to serialize an Avro data into Kafka using Schema Registry, Spark SQL, Kafka and Avro.

I tried to utilize `to_avro` method that accepts only the `column` parameter. I want to utilize the `schema` registry to write into Kafka an Avro data. Schema registry normally returns an ID to identify an Avro schema.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You are using which big data distribution platform ?

Comment: No, I use just spark !

Comment: This will help you https://blog.xebia.fr/2018/10/25/spark-structured-streaming-avec-kafka-schema-registry/